# Syntax error starting apache on osx

Tags: apache

I recently updated osx and have been unable to enable apache this is the the error I get with sudo achachetl configtest

`AH00526: Syntax error on line 21 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf:
Invalid command 'Alias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Mac-mini:~ iZayk$`

Comment: Have you checked that line of the config file for any obvious errors? Can you post the file here?

Comment: Do you have mod_alias enabled?